# vtkOrientationMarkerWidget embedded in QTWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, vtk

I have embedded the vtkOrientationMarkerWidget to the QTWidget as an axes indicator, but I met a problem there arises a bug:

> ERROR: In C:\Dev\Soft\vtk\source\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 217
> vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (00000278F82D1AD0): wglMakeCurrent failed in MakeCurrent(), error: Handle
> Invalid

when I multiply generate QTWidget instances by clicking the button.
**Because I want to add some buttons in the 3D view, I use QTWidget as a container, which is the root cause of the problem. Are there some solutions for this?**
My environment is Python 3.8+PyQT5.15.0+VTK9.0.1

The code is:

1. The main window:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDesktopWidget, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton
from axes_widget import VTKWidget2
from axes import Axes
from axes2 import Axes2

class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.window.resize(500, 400)
        self.window.move(300, 310)

        self.button = QPushButton('3D', self.window)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click_3d)
        self.button.move(380, 80)

    def click_3d(self):
        self._win_vtk = VTKWidget2()
        self._win_vtk.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    widget_ins=Widget()
    widget_ins.window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

2. The VTK window:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDesktopWidget, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
import sys
import vtk
import vtkmodules.qt
vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRWIBase = "QGLWidget"
# QGLWidget as the base class of the QVTKRenderWindowInteractor, instead of QWidget.
# This change is because it is reported that sometimes QWidget can cause rendering problems.
from vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from serum import dependency, singleton, inject

# @singleton
class VTKWidget2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VTKWidget2, self).__init__(parent)

        self.camera_focal_point = [0, 0, 0]
        self.camera_position = [-4500, 0, 0]
        self.camera_view_up = [0, -1, 0]  # default, [0,1,0]

        self.camera_azimuth = 0  # -20
        self.camera_zoom = 1.8  # 1.75

        self.z_angle = 0
        self.x_angle = 0
        self.y_angle = 0
        self.x_transform = 200
        self.y_transform = -900  # -820
        self.z_transform = 1000

        # vtk.vtkOutputWindow.SetGlobalWarningDisplay(0)
        self.initial()

    def initial(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("3D_Model")
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        screen = QDesktopWidget().geometry()
        self.self_size = self.geometry()
        self.move(int((screen.width() - self.self_size.width()) / 2),
                  int((screen.height() - self.self_size.height()) / 2))  #

        self.colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

        # Create an actor
        # self.actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        self.left_text_actor = vtk.vtkTextActor()
        self.right_text_actor = vtk.vtkTextActor()

        # A renderer and render window
        self.renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        # renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
        # renderWindow.SetWindowName("Display Coordinate Axes")
        # renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

        # An interactor
        # renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        # renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
        self.renderWindowInteractor = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
        self.renderWindow = self.renderWindowInteractor.GetRenderWindow()
        self.renderWindow.AddRenderer(self.renderer)

        # Add the actors to the scene
        # self.renderer.AddActor(self.actor)
        self.renderer.SetBackground(self.colors.GetColor3d("SlateGray"))

        # add mouse interaction mode
        vtkStyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
        # vtkStyle = MyInteractorStyle(self.renderWindow)
        # vtkStyle =  vtk.vtkInteractorStyleSwitch()
        # vtkStyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor() 
        self.renderWindowInteractor.SetInteractorStyle(vtkStyle)
        # self.renderWindow.GetInteractor().SetInteractorStyle(vtkStyle)

        self.transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
        self.transform.Translate(self.x_transform, self.y_transform, self.z_transform)

        # set axes
        self.add_axes()

        self.vtkCamera = vtk.vtkCamera()
        self.update_camera()

        frame = QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)  # QMainWindow's property
        vl = QVBoxLayout()
        vl.addWidget(self.renderWindowInteractor)
        # vl.addWidget(self.widget)  # problem: wrong: no widget for QT
        frame.setLayout(vl)

        # Begin mouse interaction
        self.renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
        self.renderWindowInteractor.Start()

    def add_axes(self):
        # set axes
        ### important: widget must be set as field, otherwise it doesn't show.
        # problem: no widget for QT
        self.widget = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
        self.axis = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
        rgba = [0] * 4
        self.colors.GetColor("Carrot", rgba)
        self.widget.SetOutlineColor(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2])
        self.widget.SetOrientationMarker(self.axis)  ### important
        self.widget.SetInteractor(self.renderWindowInteractor)
        self.widget.SetViewport(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4)
        self.widget.SetEnabled(1)
        self.widget.InteractiveOn()

    def update_camera(self):
        self.renderer.ResetCamera()
        self.renderer.SetActiveCamera(self.vtkCamera)
        self.vtkCamera.SetFocalPoint(self.camera_focal_point)
        self.vtkCamera.SetPosition(self.camera_position)
        self.vtkCamera.SetViewUp(self.camera_view_up)
        self.vtkCamera.Azimuth(self.camera_azimuth)  
        self.vtkCamera.Zoom(self.camera_zoom)
        self.renderWindow.Render()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `Widget.click_3d(self)`. Every time you click the button you reassign a new `VTKWidget2` to `self._win_vtk`. Since `self._win_vtk` is the only reference in your program to any of the `VTKWidget2` windows, as soon as you assign a new value to `self._win_vtk`, the previous `VTKWidget2` window will be deleted by the garbage collector (which apparently causes problems with the underlying `QGLWidget`). One way around this is to make a persistent reference to all the windows, for example by putting them in a list, e.g.

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        self.vtk_windows = []


    def click_3d(self):
        win = VTKWidget2()
        self.vtk_windows.append(win)
        win.show()
```

This still causes a bunch of errors when the last window is closed an the program exits which seems to be cause by using a QGLWidget as the base of your QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned, Python has garbage collector mechanism,  when the variable is assigned to a new object reference, the previous object will be deleted. If I want to keep one instance, this usage doesn't matter. Because I want to add some buttons in the view, I use QTWidget as a container, which is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Although, I comment `vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRWIBase = "QGLWidget"`. The problem still exists.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong. The `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` is a widget itself and you can add this directly to a layout. I can recommend watching this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FPXKP3kqK8&t=197s&ab_channel=cscsch

Comment: @JensMunk Wrong in what way? The QVTKRenderWindowInteractor is added to a layout: the layout of the central widget of VTKWidget2.

Comment: Sry, my bad. The video is pretty cool though